# C# UdpClient not receiving

Tags: c#, sockets, udpclient

I am having some issues with System.Net.Socket's `UdpClient` today. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I have another UWP specific implementation using the Windows namespace which works perfectly, but I can't crack this.

I have a server sending UDP packets to my client from an arbitrary port to `localPort`. The client will occasionally send a packet back to `remoteHostname:remotePort`. However, I never seem to get any of this data out of `EndReceive`.

I can see on Wireshark (and my server) that I'm correctly managing to send packets via `Send` from the client to the server, and that the server is indeed sending packets to the client with the correct destination port (`localPort`). Any ideas would be amazing. Here's the class:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class UdpReceiver
{
    private UdpClient Client;
    private AsyncCallback InternalCallback;
    private IPEndPoint Destination;
    private IPEndPoint Listen;
    private bool Transmit = false;

    public UdpReceiver(string remoteHostname, int remotePort, int localPort, int depth)
    {
        Destination = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(remoteHostname), remotePort);
        Listen = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, localPort);

        Client = new UdpClient(localPort);    
        InternalCallback = MakeCallback();
        Client.BeginReceive(InternalCallback, null);
    }

    public void Send(byte[] data)
    {
        if (!Transmit)
        {
            Transmit = true;
            Client.BeginSend(data, data.Length, Destination, InternalCallback, null);
        }
    }

    private AsyncCallback MakeCallback()
    {
        return new AsyncCallback((result) =>
        {
            if (Transmit)
            {
                Client.EndSend(result);
                Transmit = false;
            }
            else
            {
                var data = Client.EndReceive(result, ref Listen);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Got some data!");
                Client.BeginReceive(InternalCallback, null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Q: Are you running Wireshark on the client, to make sure the packets are actually getting through?  Q: Perhaps a firewall issue?

Comment: Is it possible that this is an object referencing issue? 
In your constructor, you create Listen (an IPEndPoint) using localport.
Then you give localport again to the UdpClient constructor, instead of Listen. It might be making its own new IPEndPoint. 
Later, you call EndReceieve with ref Listen. It might be comparing the anonymous IPEndPoint with Listen and deciding they are different objects?

TLDR: Try giving Listen to the UdpClient constructor instead of localport.

Comment: @paulsm4 yep Wireshark on the client shows the packets. The UWP version running on the same client also works fine.

Comment: @ThorynHawley good idea but I've actually been doing it as you suggested for the most part (but not in the example above) so not that I'm afraid :(

Comment: Q: If your client is on Windows, what happens if you (temporarily!) turn off Windows firewall (and any A/V firewall you might also have running)?  Q: What happens if your client listens on a specific port?  Any change, in either case?